# `babel`, french, spacing colon and LaTeX3

Tags: babel, latex3

I have a problem with the code below, where the first line printed `Test : OK ?` is not the same as the second one `Test: OK ?` with a mising spacing

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

Test: OK ?

\ExplSyntaxOn

Test: ~ OK ?

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Why are you printing code inside `\ExplSyntaxOn ... `\ExplSyntaxOff` in the first place? That is for code definitions.

Comment: Yes, I will use some translations inside LaTeX3 functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ExplSyntaxOn` makes `:` a letter, so the shorthand doesn’t work any more, but `babel` provides a macro that allows to use it in any context (even with `shorthands=off`):

```
Test\babelshorthand{:} ~ OK ?
```

You can also make `:` active again, but I presume this piece of text belongs to a package written in LaTeX3, so it’s not an option.

Comment: I'm so stupid on such a hot day... :-)